# Deleting rows in Excel where a cell value is not repeated in other rows

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with 1,362 rows of data. There is date in Column A and an ID # in Column B. The rest of the columns contain item scores for an assessment and some calculations based on those item scores. There are 1053 unique ID #'s and 201 ID #'s that repeat at least once. Some of the ID #'s repeat more than once. I want to delete rows so that I end up with the first and last measure ***only*** for each ID# that repeated. That means I need to delete all the rows for ID #'s that occurred only once; and I need to repeat all the rows for ID #'s that were repeated but were ***not*** the first or last instance. I did this with a smaller data set (a few hundred) a couple of months ago and I will have to keep doing this as the data set grows into the future, where there could be many thousands of rows. When I did it last time, I  sorted the data by ID # and by date, then I went through manually and deleted all the rows I didn't want. I've started doing it the same way this time but I realize it's taking too long and will take an eternity once the data set gets bigger. Your help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! Well written questions generally get faster and better answers. You might want to edit your question and include the part of your code that seems to have a problem, a sample of the data that can be used to reproduce the error, and an example of your expected output https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: For a first question in SO he has worded it very clearly and well ..compared to the usual non English speaking "give me code. Now " questions. So I can forgive him for not sharing code . He virtually has by his well explained question. He has also explained what he has tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some helper columns to help you sort/delete the rows you don't want. Consider the following screenshot.

The data is sorted by ID and then by date, so all duplicate IDs are in adjacent rows.

The formula in column "helper 1" creates a running count for each ID.

```
=IF(B2<>B1,1,C1+1)
```

The formula in column "helper 2" then identifies the first and the last number for each ID and flags it.

```
=IF(C2=1,IF(OR(ISBLANK(C3),C3=1),"delete","keep"),IF(C2>C3,"keep","delete"))
```

Now you need to copy the Helper 2 column and paste it as values, so the results don't change when the data is sorted differently. Next, sort by Helper 2 (which now has text, not formulas) and delete all rows with the flag "delete".

Takes less than a minute.

[image]

Comment: if that resolves your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it doesn't, leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: Thanks so much! You have helped a behavioral healthcare agency learn more about the outcomes we are achieving for our patients. Bravo!

Comment: Teylyn's answer allowed me to resolve my first question. Now I have 14 columns of data for which I need to calculate T Tests for the values in alternate rows. I want to embed a formula in cells that will automatically calculate T Tests for the pairs of data in the alternating rows for each variable. I know I can copy all  the data for alternating rows and copy them into a new table as contiguous rows, but this is very time consuming, especially for 14 variables and especially as the data set grow to thousands. Thanks for any help you can give with this.

Comment: @DonaldMott Please start a new question for this. Per site rules, one question per post. It doesn't cost anything and will get more attention than a comment in an answered question.

Comment: Thanks, Teylyn. I actually figured this one myself! Yay. Thanks again for your original help. Next time I'll know to post a new question separately.